# Finding the length of a JoinableQueue in Gevent

Tags: python, queue, gevent

I've been trying to find the length of a `JoinableQueue` in Gevent but it throws an error saying that the queue is not iterable.

Is there a way I can find out the number of items enqueued before I start popping items from it.

Thanks

Comment: Always, always look in the docs first. It'll probably be there.

Comment: You're right Joel. I should've RTFD. I've been working with Gevent for a while now and mainly got into it through the help of it's docs but somehow overlooked/missed this one. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html):

```
class gevent.queue.Queue(maxsize=None)
    [...]
    qsize()

        Return the size of the queue.

[...]
class gevent.queue.JoinableQueue(maxsize=None)
    A subclass of Queue
```

So, I think you could use: `your_queue.qsize()`